# Java Virtual Machine Heap Size Format as Percentage of Memory

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, jvm-arguments

I have installed an IDBS Spreadsheet server on my application server and found that it has a format for the JVM heap sizes that I'm unfamiliar with. The documentation mentions that the xmx or maximum heap size is set to be 75% of the memory of the system. The format in the ini file is this

> -Xms50:1024:1536P -Xmx75:1536P

I've never seen this format in my searches for documentation. I can guess that the 75 means 75% and maybe the P indicates percentage instead of the usual G for gigabytes and M for megabytes, but I'm not sure what the 1536 means or how to read the xms 3 number value.

Comment: That may be subject of whoever reads and parses the INI file rather than the JVM itself…